# How do I export the data generated by ODEINT (imported from scipy.integrate) to Excel?

Tags: excel, ode, pandas.excelwriter

I solved a simple ODE using ODEINT, that results in the data being held in (t,y). How do I export that data to Excel?

I can add that I tried using pd.DataFrame and ended up having all data written as two long strings (a string of all t-data in row 1 and a string of all y-data in row 2). I would actually like all t-data to appear in column-1 and all y-data to appear in column-2.

Comment: Get the data in excel then use transpose, as in copy then paste special transpose.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be a method that does not require intervention in Excel, but your method worked indeed.